# Is this definition of "sequentially compact" ok? ("Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.) Need to modify it?

Tags: definition, compactness

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

The definition of "sequentially compact" in this book is like the following:

> Let $S$ be a metric space.
> $S$ is said to be sequentially compact if every sequence of points of $S$ has a convergent subsequence.

The author proved the following theorem:

> Theorem 12 on p.266:
> Let $S$ be a metric space.
> $S$ is compact if and only if $S$ is sequentially compact.

For example, let $S=(0,1)$.
Let $(a_n)$ be an arbitrary sequence in $S$.
Then, $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence.
So, by Bolzano - Weierstrass Theorem in Calculus, $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.
So, $(a_n)$ is sequentially compact by the author's definition.
So, by Theorem 12, $S=(0,1)$ is compact.
But this is not correct.

So, I think the following definition is correct:

> Let $S$ be a metric space.
> $S$ is said to be sequentially compact if every sequence of points of $S$ has a convergent subsequence which converges to a point in $S$.

Is the author's definition of "sequentially compact" ok?
Or do we need to modify it?

Comment: The point in your example is that you are seeing $(0,1)$ as a subspace of a bigger space. If you see $(0,1)$ as an entity "per se", not embedded in other structure, the sequence $1/n$ has no convergent subsequence, for example.

Comment: @CélioAugusto Thank you very much for your comment.